# Force expansion of an expression inside a Clojure macro

Tags: macros, clojure

I am trying to use Stuart Sierra's [`do-template`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.template-api.html) macro inside a `defprotocol` and the Clojure compiler complains that I am redefining `do-template` -- not what I intend:

```
(defprotocol AProtocol
  (a-method [_])
  (do-template [name]
    `(~(symbol (str name "-method")) [this that])
    foo
    bar
    baz))
```

This should expand to:

```
(defprotocol AProtocol
  (a-method [_])
  (foo-method [this that])
  (bar-method [this that])
  (baz-method [this that]))
```

The problem (I believe) is that the `do-template` s-expression is getting passed to `defprotocol` unexpanded. Is there any way to cause it to evaluate before being passed?

BTW, `do-template` should actually expand to

```
(do
  (foo-method [this that])
  (bar-method [this that])
  (baz-method [this that]))
```

but I already tried that (with a hand-expanded version) and `defprotocol` is fine with the nested `do`.

How can I see the actual expansion of the `do-template`? I tried both `(macroexpand '(do-template ...))` and `(macroexpand-1 '(do-template ...))` and got:

> (do (clojure.core/seq
>   (clojure.core/concat
>   (clojure.core/list (symbol (str foo
>   "-method"))) (clojure.core/list
>   (clojure.core/apply
>   clojure.core/vector (clojure.core/seq
>   (clojure.core/concat
>   (clojure.core/list (quote user/this))
>   (clojure.core/list (quote
>   user/that)))))))) (clojure.core/seq
>   (clojure.core/concat
>   (clojure.core/list (symbol (str bar
>   "-method"))) (clojure.core/list
>   (clojure.core/apply
>   clojure.core/vector (clojure.core/seq
>   (clojure.core/concat
>   (clojure.core/list (quote user/this))
>   (clojure.core/list (quote
>   user/that)))))))) (clojure.core/seq
>   (clojure.core/concat
>   (clojure.core/list (symbol (str baz
>   "-method"))) (clojure.core/list
>   (clojure.core/apply
>   clojure.core/vector (clojure.core/seq
>   (clojure.core/concat
>   (clojure.core/list (quote user/this))
>   (clojure.core/list (quote
>   user/that)))))))))

Not exactly easy to read :-).

Also, I probably want the `this` and `that` to be *anaphora* and expand to themselves: `~'this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) defprotocol is not fine with a do form. It doesn't raise an error, but it doesn't work either.

(2) You can't do what you want in this way.  defprotocol is the macro being called, so it has absolute authority about how sub-forms are expanded.

(3) Item (2) suggests a solution, in fact the same one as at least one of your recent questions: define a new macro, say `with-methods`, that takes a list of method names, followed by whatever other defprotocol arguments, and expands into a defprotocol with the appropriate substitutions and splicing already done, so that defprotocol can expand in peace without needing to know anything about your do-template trick.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to write `build-protocol` and `build-reify` macros to create the appropriate structures, each with a signature something like `(build-protocol name simple & complex)` where `simple` is a vector of "simple" declarations (`(a-method [this])`) and `complex` is zero or more forms that get inserted with `~@`.