# build-protocol Clojure macro

Tags: macros, clojure

As a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402316/force-expansion-of-an-expression-inside-a-clojure-macro), I am trying to write a macro that builds a `defprotocol`:

```
(build-protocol AProtocol
  [(a-method [this]) (b-method [this that])]
  (map (fn [name] `(~(symbol (str name "-method")) [~'this ~'that ~'the-other]))
    ["foo" "bar" "baz"])
  (map (fn [name] `(~(symbol (str name "-method")) [~'_]))
    ["hello" "goodbye"]))
```

should expand to

```
(defprotocol AProtocol
  (a-method [this])
  (b-method [this that])
  (foo-method [this that the-other])
  (bar-method [this that the-other])
  (baz-method [this that the-other])
  (hello-fn [_])
  (goodbye-fn [_]))
```

My attempt:

```
(defmacro build-protocol [name simple & complex]
  `(defprotocol ~name ~@simple
     ~@(loop [complex complex ret []]
         (if (seq complex)
           (recur (rest complex) (into ret (eval (first complex))))
           ret))))
```

and expansion `(macroexpand-1 '(...))`:

```
(clojure.core/defprotocol AProtocol
  (a-method [this])
  (b-method [this that])
  (foo-method [this that the-other])
  (bar-method [this that the-other])
  (baz-method [this that the-other])
  (hello-method [_])
  (goodbye-method [_]))
```

I'm not really happy about the `eval`. Also, the `map` expressions are pretty ugly. Is there a better way? Any and all comments welcome.

Once I get this working, I'm going to do a similar macro for `(build-reify ...)`. I'm writing a rather large Swing application and have several components (`JButton`s, `JCheckBox`es, etc.) that have almost identical method signatures and actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're doing it upside down. Specify the "-method" stuff first, wrapped in a container of some kind so build-protocol knows what's what, and let it do the map inside the macro. e.g:

```
(build-protocol AProtocol
  {[this that whatever] [foo bar baz],
   [_] [hello goodbye]}
  ; a-method and b-method...
)
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll have to explore it.

Comment: See, for example, https://github.com/amalloy/ordered/blob/develop/src/deftype/delegate.clj - I wrote this over the weekend and checked it in this morning. It defines a new `delegating-deftype` (seen in use at https://github.com/amalloy/ordered/blob/develop/src/ordered/map.clj), in much the same way I recommended you do `build-protocol`.

Comment: @Ralph I went ahead and implemented a rough draft of this for you so you can see what I mean: https://github.com/amalloy/build-protocol/blob/develop/src/build_protocol/core.clj

Comment: I looked at your example at https://github.com/amalloy/build-protocol/blob/develop/src/build_protocol/core.clj. I like it. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting ready to try a `(grid-bag-panel...)` following the example Stuart Sierra did in his blog (http://stuartsierra.com/2010/01/05/taming-the-gridbaglayout), but I have some ideas of my own. The **best** way to learn this stuff is to actually do it (reading only goes so far).